# Relay command getting fired twice on rare occasions

Tags: wpf

We have a kiosk application and have a button which fires a particular command which navigates to a screen.
But what is happening on rare occasion is it is fires the method attached with the relay command twice which is causing problems.

**Here is the XAML Code**

```
   <Button Grid.Row="{Binding Row}" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Style="{StaticResource PaymentScreenButton}" Command="{Binding PayCommand}">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                      Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                      Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=ActualHeight}">
                        <Grid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding BackgroundImageSource,Converter={StaticResource NullImageConverter}}"/>
                        </Grid.Background>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height=".4*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,0,0"
                              Visibility="{Binding IsButtonTextAndImageVisible,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" >
                            <!--<Path Style="{StaticResource IconPath1Style}"/>
                            <Path Style="{StaticResource IconPath2Style}"/>-->
                            <Image  Style="{StaticResource PayImage}" Margin="0,10,0,0" Visibility="{Binding IsButtonTextAndImageVisible,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Height="{Binding LeftBlockImageheight}" />
                        </Grid>

                        <TextBlock Text="PAY" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource BigText}" VerticalAlignment="Top"  
                                   Visibility="{Binding IsButtonTextAndImageVisible,Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" FontSize="{Binding LeftBlockFontSize}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
```

**Followed by ViewModel Code**

```
 public RelayCommand PayCommand
        {
            get { return _payCommand ?? (_payCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Pay())); }
        }

  private void Pay()
{  
   if (IsBusy)
     return;

    IsBusy = true;

    LogHelper.LogFile(nameof(Pay), $"Pay called", false, LogType.UnlimitedLogs);

    StopAudio();

    AppMessenger.Send(new AppMessage() { MessageType = AppMessageType.Navigate, MessageData = new NavigationMessageData() { NavigationTarget = NavigationPages.PaymentScreen } });

}
```

**Here are the logs**

```
    2021-04-27 11:08:42.300 MethodName=Pay, Message=Paycalled
    2021-04-27 11:08:42.306,MethodName=PayViewModel, Message=PayViewModel called
    2021-04-27 11:08:42.741,MethodName=Pay, Message=Paycalled
    2021-04-27 11:08:42.746,MethodName=PayViewModel, Message=PayViewModelcalled
```

They are showing that the Relay Command fired in the matter of milliseconds between each other, Thus calling the same method twice. The issue is that, we cannot even put IsBusy flag as these methods are virtually getting called at the same time thus bypassing any checks put there to prevent it.

My Question is
Can this be related to the underlying WPF framework issue ?
And does it has anything to do with the Touch screens Kiosk use ?

And is there a way to prevent it from happening ?

Thanks for all the help guys

Comment: Disable the button as soon as it is clicked. And enable the button only after the execution of relaycommand is completed. Observe if the command is still getting executed twice.

Comment: Thanks Abbas, I would like to try it for sure.

Any idea why it might be firing twice ?

Comment: Because users can double click a button or get frustrated and click a button whilst it's processing i always have an isbusy property on my base viewmodel. In the command check if isbusy and return if true. Set isbusy true. Process. Set isbusy false. Don't just rely on disabling the button.

Comment: Thanks Andy, It make sense. 
Even though the navigation happens below 1 second of time and we never able to replicate it when trying in our end. 
Do you think IsBusy check would work when firing time of both these methods are like 200 mill seconds after other ?

Comment: I just updated the above code with IsBusy flag, Would it work this way ?

Comment: Remember to set it false.

Comment: Sure, Thanks a lot for your help.  I will do both of these steps and see if it helps us.

Comment: Where does the PayViewModel message come from? Are you sure that the methods are called so fast that you can't even put the busy flag? To me a difference of 440ms looks more like the first call completed before the second one starts... 440ms are basically enough time for a computer to write an essay of your whole life, not just write a single boolean property.

Comment: Hi grek, 
Yes you are right. I am thinking more in slow motion due to debugging the code but yes 330 ms looks like more than enough seconds if you put it that way.  I will try the IsBusy flag and hopefully this will sort out the problem. 
Thanks for the putting things in context.

Comment: Just extend your command to check "CanPay(bool)" and you are done.

Comment: Do you have anything indicates the user paid already? Because that'd be something else to check.